# Обособление оборота "как на праздник"

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Уважаемые участники форума! Помогите, пожалуйста, определить, правильно ли обособлен сравнительный оборот в приведенных примерах, а также объяснить решение в каждом случае:

(1) Мы тоже шли на спектакль, как на праздник, и старались не обмануть ожиданий тех, кто приходил слушать нас.

(2) Делать доклад он шёл как на праздник.

(3) Я оделась со всякою тщательностью, как на праздник.

(4) Стервятник оделся, как на праздник, и принес шоколад, маскируя цель своего визита.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В четвертом запятая, думаю не нужна. Здесь от смысла, конечно, зависит... Но представляется, что это не сравнение а единый оборот в роли обстоятельства. Вряд ли "Стервятник" как-то по особому одевался именно на праздники. Т.е. это означает просто "красиво, нарядно".

Остальное - согласен.
(+)
Сравните, кстати, четвертое со вторым. Тот же случай. Запятая не нужна.
(++)
Тут еще с первым стоит подумать, тоже ведь можно интерпретировать не как сравнение, а как обстоятельство, но это уже некоторая натяжка.

Comment: Я думаю, что Стервятник не был до этого одет, поэтому на первом плане излагается сам факт того, что он оделся. А на втором плане (между прочим) указывается, что оделся он нарядно. Но все предложение включает разнообразное содержание, поэтому автор решил оборот  обособить. Попробуйте прочитать предложение без обособления, и оно будет звучать как-то плоско, невыразительно, будет вытянуто в линейную цепочку..

Comment: Возможно, конечно... Но надо бы исходный текст найти, без этого - гадание на кофейной гуще. ---- нашел. лучше не стало ))) Вообще Тяжелый текст для пунктуационных изысканий.

Comment: http://fictionbook.in/mariam-petrosyan-dom-v-kotorom.html

Answer (score 1):

Во втором я бы тоже поставил запятую. Чем второе отличается от первого и четвёртого?
В третьем я бы сказал, что уточнение.Оделась (как?) со всякою тщательностью, (как именно?) как на праздник.

Comment: Согласна, что в третьем предложении уточнение.  Но мне кажется, что знаки расставлены верно, так что остается ваш вопрос: чем второе отличается от первого и четвёртого?

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах(кроме второго) содержится сравнение и оборот не связан тесно со сказуемым. Поэтому запятая ставится.

Запятая во втором предложении не нужна, оборот тесно связан со сказуемым. Сказуемое без оборота не имеет законченного смысла.

Однако в некоторых случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация.
Запятая перед как не ставится, если сравнительный оборот выступает в роли сказуемого. Когда же речь идет именно о сравнении, то в одинаковых условиях запятая может ставится, а может и не ставится.

***>Ср.: Отсюда вся громадная территория порта обычна видна как на ладони. 
     С вершины все окрестности были видны, как на ладони.***

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э. Стр.283.

Comment: "Мы  шли на спектакль, как на праздник. Делать доклад он шёл как на праздник". Почему в одном случае тесная связь со сказуемым, а в другом нет?  Или вот: Он оделся как на праздник (нет обособления, тесная связь). А в четвертом предложении почему обособляется такой же вариант?

Comment: Вера, в втором примере. сказуемое без оборота не имеет законченного смысла. В четвертом примере запятая может ставится, когда на первый план выступает сравнение. Оделся так, словно на праздник. Без запятой сообщается просто факт. здесь,как я написал в с воем ответе, возможно двоякая пунктуация. В четвертом примере не ощущается тесная связь со сказуемом. Сказуемое без оборота имеет законченный смысл.

Comment: *Делать доклад он шёл как на праздник. Он шёл делать доклад, как на праздник.* От порядка слов, что ли, зависит?! Нет, не думаю. А тогда запятая нужна.

Comment: Серж, я понимаю вашу мысль о законченном/незаконченном смысле сказуемого, но я не уверена в правильности вашей терминологии. Сказуемое - шел, делать доклад - инфинитив в роли обстоятельства цели. Дело не в сказуемом, а в предложении, неотъемлемым содержанием которого является оборот, и поэтому его нельзя обособить (тема-рема, по принципу.актуального членения).